# How to add class in title div for specific block?

Tags: views, blocks

I have created a block using Views module in website using drupal 7.
My block title's HTML structure is as bellow:

```
<div class="titleHeader clearfix">
   <h3>BLOCK_TITLE</h3>
</div>
```

I want to add a class in `<div>`.
Should I create a module for this or any other way?
Please guide me how can I do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should first search in Google then post somewhere.

Comment: Yes I had and found a way by using module. But it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function themename_preprocess_block(&$variables) {

```
if($variables['block']->bid == 'views-front-block') {

     $variables['classes_array'][] = 'container';
 }
```

}

add this function in your template.php file of your theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Block Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class) module will allow you to add classes in blocks. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows users to add classes to any block through the block's configuration interface. By adding a very short snippet of PHP to a theme's block.tpl.php file, classes can be added to the parent `<div class="block ...">` element of a block. Hooray for more powerful block theming!

Comment: It just add class in <div> of block. I want to add class in <div> for title of the block.

Comment: You can use sibling selector in CSS to do so( http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Comment: I want to add bootstrap.css class in this <div> so it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your view -> Edit -> Expand Advanced Fieldset -> Theme: Information. Copy the template suggestion from Style output (Display output? I can't really remember) container and create that file (Do not forget to clean the cache). Then copy the default code and modify it. For ex.:

```
<?php print $wrapper_prefix; ?>
  <?php if (!empty($title)) : ?>
    <div class="myClass"><h3><span><?php print $title; ?></span></h3></div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print $list_type_prefix; ?>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
      <li class="<?php print $classes_array[$id]; ?>"><?php print $row; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php print $list_type_suffix; ?>
<?php print $wrapper_suffix; ?>
```